# how to prove if $\omega\wedge \text{d}\omega=0$ then locally $\omega=h\text{d}f$.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, general-relativity

I see this in general relativity, and it is "locally synchronizable" implies "synchronizable" locally, where we say a reference frame  $Q$ (future-point vector field such that $g(Q,Q)=-1$) is "locally synchronizable" if the associated 1-form $\omega$ satisfies $\omega\wedge \text{d}\omega=0$ and $Q$ is "synchronizable" if there exist smooth functions such that $\omega=h\text{d}f$.

I can not find a proof for this.

Is it true for general (semi-)Riemannian manifold?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: This is a special case of the [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(differential_topology)). The condition $\omega\wedge d\omega = 0$ implies that the distribution defined by the kernel of $\omega$ is involutive, and thus there are local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ in which $\omega$ is a smooth multiple of $x^1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotational free 1-form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462341/rotational-free-1-form)

Comment: @JackLee: You meant $dx^1$, of course. :) And, no metrics whatsoever needed, DisplayName, just a manifold structure. But it's still just local — I'm confused about whether you require your functions $f,h$ to be global.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Oops, right. Thanks, Ted.